# How does events package work in node.js in contrast of event listeners of browser Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am really confused about how events and event handlers are working inside the browser and node.js.

For example, in the browser when we have a script like this:

```js
const btnEl = ...

btnEl.addEventListener("click" ,() => console.log("handler callback"));

for (let index = 0; index < 100000; index++) {
  console.log(index)
}
```

We all already know that during the for loop and till the end of the current operation which is the current anonymous function, every click event will not work because the call stack is not empty and the event loop will queue the click messages for getting called later.

But in node.js I see different behaviour, like this code:

```js
const EventEmitter = require("events");

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on("start", (start, end) => {
  console.log(`started from ${start} to ${end}`);
});

for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
  if (index === 10) {
    eventEmitter.emit("start", 1, 100);
  } else {
    console.log(index);
  }
}
```

In this code, when I emit the event, it breaks the current cycle in the for loop and then executes the callback, which opposes the principles of being single-threaded of the Javascript engine.

Can someone explain to me why it is working like this?

Here is the output of the second code:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
started from 1 to 100
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Comment: [Node Events docs - Asynchronous vs. synchronous](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous)

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples are nothing like one another.

`eventEmitter.emit("start", 1, 100);` in nodejs is a synchronous piece of code.  It doesn't go through the event loop at all.  It's just a function call that cycles through any listeners for the `start` message and calls those listeners.  It's just plain synchronous Javascript.  The fact that they call things "events" is probably confusing things as they have nothing to do with the event loop.

A user click in the browser, on the other hand, goes through the event loop and needs the Javascript interpreter to be available so it can grab the next waiting event and then call the click handler.

In nodejs, an incoming event such as an incoming network connection or the completion of a file read operation are more analogous to a browser user click event as they go through the event loop and must wait until the current Javascript is done executing an thus the next event can be pulled from the event queue.

FYI, if you want something more comparable in nodejs, look at this:

```
for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
  if (index === 10) {
    setImmediate(() => eventEmitter.emit("start", 1, 100));
  } else {
    console.log(index);
  }
}
```

Then, you're forcing the `.emit()` to go through the event loop and it will get delayed until after the `for` loop is done.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude!

Comment: @MohammadMahdiMohajer - I added an example in nodejs that would make it go through the event loop.